# Steering wheel vibrations at highway speeds

Tags: ford, vibration, escape

I got a 2012 Ford Escape 3.0 L with about 85,000 miles on it and brake pads have about 4 months on them.

When I drive on the expressway and I get to about 70+ mph the steering wheel shakes like I'm riding over rocks. This last the entire time I'm over the speed limit, I mean over 70 mph.

What could this shaking come from?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tires, or a front wheel has thrown a balancing weight would be my first assumption.  Examine both front tires for uneven wear, "cupping" (scalloped depressions where tread gets shallow in evenly spaced pockets around the circumference).  If the tires appear fine everywhere, it may simply be that a balancing weight has come off.

After that, there might be a tie rod going bad.  But the specific speed occurrence you describe is likely a tire issue.

Your local tire shop should be able to provide an *evaluation* for *free*.  If not, find one that does.

Comment: This could also be an out of balance wheel AND a broken or worn out shock absorber.  That would make the condition much more noticeable inside the car.

Comment: And cause cupped wear on that tire, too!  Good catch @zipit